# Why My Html file does not recognize AngularJS variables

Tags: html, angularjs

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="">
<head>
    <title>hello</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <input type="text" ng-model="name">
 <p>{{name}} </p>
</html>
```

I try to do a very simple angular project, but there is something wrong. In the output page variables names appeared, not values as expected.

Comment: You should add a [snippet of code](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) and run that can help us.

Comment: Post your code  here

Comment: sorry , I edited it

Comment: I dont think its a valid Angular code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the module and controller declared, those two are missing with your code,

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
    app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {

    });
```

**DEMO**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
 <input type="text" ng-model="name">
 <p>{{name}} </p>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: still same problem .. 
it worked here .. But on my spring tool , it does not work

Comment: pasword also share here

Answer (score 0):

Check sample angularjs code

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.name = "Hello";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="name">
    <p>{{name}} </p>
  </div>
</body>
```